# How to compare values between two different associative arrays in Bash?

Tags: bash, associative-array

```
declare -A hm1
declare -A hm2
hm1["a"]=1
hm1["b"]=2
hm2["a"]=5
hm2["b"]=2
```

I would like to check if for the same key, that if the values are different then do something

eg. `if [ hm1["a"] -eq hm2["a"] ] => implies if [ 1 == 5 ]; then do something ...`

Comment: Use `-ne` (integer not equals) instead of `-eq` (integer equals)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you got the syntax wrong - outside of numeric context, you would refer to your variables using i.e. `${hm1[a]}` and not a plain `hm1["a"]`, I suggest that you **do** the comparision in numeric context, because in this case you can write the array references simpler, i.e.

```
if (( hm1[a] == hm2[a] ))
then 
  ...
```

instead of the cumbersome

```
if [ ${hm1[a]} -eq ${hm2[a]} ]
then
  ....
```

Of course for checking for difference, you would use a

```
if (( hm1[a] != hm2[a] ))
then 
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare -A hm1
declare -A hm2
hm1["a"]=1
hm1["b"]=2
hm1["c"]=2
hm2["a"]=5
hm2["b"]=2

# compare values if exist and return 0/1
function areDifferent (){
    local key=$1
    # key does not exist in hm2
    [ -z ${hm2[$key]} ] && return 0 
    # compare values
    [ ${hm1[$key]} -ne ${hm2[$key]} ] && return 0 || return 1
}

# iterate through hm1 keys 
for k in ${!hm1[@]}
do
   # call compare function
   if areDifferent $k;
   then
    # areDifferent is true
    echo "values for key $k are different"
    # do some 
   fi
done
```

output

```
values for key a are different
values for key c are different
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- array keys could contain white space
- arrays may not contain the same set of indices
- array values may not be numeric (ie, we'll be comparing strings)

Sample data:

```
declare -A hm1
declare -A hm2

hm1["a"]=1
hm1["b"]=2
hm1["c d"]=3
hm1["e"]=12

hm2["a"]=5
hm2["b"]=2
hm2["c"]=7
hm2["e"]=twelve
```

Obtain unique list of all indices:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${!hm1[@]}" "${!hm2[@]}" | sort -u
a
b
c
c d
e
```

Loop through list of indices performing appropriate tests:

```
while read -r key
do
    [[ -z "${hm1[$key]}" ]] && echo "hm1[$key] does not exist" && continue
    [[ -z "${hm2[$key]}" ]] && echo "hm2[$key] does not exist" && continue

    [[ "${hm1[$key]}" == "${hm2[$key]}" ]] && echo "hm1[$key]=${hm1[$key]} == ${hm2[$key]}=hm2[$key]" && continue

    # at this point they are different so ...

    echo "hm1[$key]=${hm1[$key]} != ${hm2[$key]}=hm2[$key]"

done < <(printf "%s\n" "${!hm1[@]}" "${!hm2[@]}" | sort -u)
```

**NOTE:** remove/replace `echo's` as appropriate

This generates:

```
hm1[a]=1 != 5=hm2[a]
hm1[b]=2 == 2=hm2[b]
hm1[c] does not exist
hm2[c d] does not exist
hm1[e]=12 != twelve=hm2[e]
```